# Q: A quadrilateral, equilateral triangles and two perpendicular lines

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, quadrilateral

I'm trying to solve the following question using complex numbers:

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with the equilateral triangles $ABE,BFC,CGD,DHA$ constructed externally on its sides. Prove that the line joining the centers (centroids) of triangles $DHA$ and $BFC$ is perpendicular  to the line joining $G$ and $E$.

My try:
Let $x$ and $y$ be the centers of the triangles $DHA$ and $BFC$, respectively.

Showing that $(E-G)i=k(x-y)$, where $k$ is a constant real number will end the proof.

Let  $\omega=e^{\tfrac{\pi i}{6}}$. Than we have all the following:

First of all, we notice that $i=\omega^3$. Now I'll use $\omega$ to express all the vertices:

$E=A+(B-A)\omega^2$

$G=C+(D-C)\omega^2$

$H=D+(A-D)\omega^2$

$G=B+(C-B)\omega^2$

$x=\frac{1}{3}(A+D+H)$

$y=\frac{1}{3}(B+C+F)$

We can also express $x$ and $y$ like this:

$x=D+\frac{1}{2}(A+D)\omega$

$y=B+\frac{1}{2}(B+C)\omega$

I was trying to combine some or all of these identities in various ways, but IT didn't yield the expected result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like  an extension of  Fermat-Toricelli point ...